# confused about complicated join request in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Basically I have 4 tables and the group id of the current group.
I'll list the important fields and info:

```
Users:
ID,
FirstName,
LastName

Groups:
ID,
participantlist_id

participantlist:
list_id

participantlist_links:
list_id,
participant_id
```

I already figured out how to show all users that are in the participantlist.list_id in the highest point of the tree with a little function:

```
SELECT Users.ID,Users.FirstName,Users.LastName FROM Users
JOIN participantlist_links ON Users.ID = participantlist_links.participant_id
JOIN participantlist ON participantlist_links.list_id = participantlist.list_id
JOIN Groups ON participantlist.list_id = Groups.participantlist_id AND 
Groups.ID = '".workspaces_tell_me_brainstorm_group_id_from_group_id($group_id)."'
```

Now I'd like to exclude all the users that are linked to the participantlist.list_id of the current group ($group_id), but I just can't figure out a good way to do it all in a single query. I think the solution is going to be some sort of left join/right or left/right outer join comparison.

My working temporary, but very time expensive solution is this:

```
SELECT table2.id as ID, table2.firstname as FirstName, table2.lastname as LastName
FROM

(SELECT table1.ID,table1.FirstName,table1.LastName FROM Users as table1
JOIN participantlist_links ON table1.ID = participantlist_links.participant_id
JOIN participantlist ON participantlist_links.list_id = participantlist.list_id
JOIN Groups ON participantlist.list_id = Groups.participantlist_id 
AND Groups.ID = '".workspaces_tell_me_brainstorm_group_id_from_group_id($group_id)."')
as table2

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT table4.ID,table4.FirstName,table4.LastName FROM Users as table4
JOIN participantlist_links ON table4.ID = participantlist_links.participant_id
JOIN participantlist ON participantlist_links.list_id = participantlist.list_id
JOIN Groups ON participantlist.list_id = Groups.participantlist_id 
AND Groups.ID = '".$group_id."') 
as table3

ON table2.ID = table3.ID WHERE table3.id is null
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something a little simpler.

I think `not in` is your friend here.  It should keep your code a little easier to read and will most likely let mysql optimize it a little more:

```
SELECT table1.ID,
       table1.FirstName,
       table1.LastName 
  FROM Users as table1
  JOIN participantlist_links ON table1.ID = participantlist_links.participant_id
  JOIN participantlist ON participantlist_links.list_id = participantlist.list_id
  JOIN Groups ON participantlist.list_id = Groups.participantlist_id 
   AND Groups.ID = '".workspaces_tell_me_brainstorm_group_id_from_group_id($group_id)."')
   AND table1.id not in (
               SELECT table4.ID
                 FROM Users as table4
                 JOIN participantlist_links ON table4.ID = participantlist_links.participant_id
                 JOIN participantlist ON participantlist_links.list_id = participantlist.list_id
                 JOIN Groups ON participantlist.list_id = Groups.participantlist_id 
                  AND Groups.ID = '".$group_id."'
                )
```